# should I use ++wordCount[key] for unordered_map<string, int> when key doesn't exist in wordCount?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

See code below:

```
unordered_map<string, int> wordCount;
for(string word: words)
    ++wordCount[word];
```

Question:

Does it right here for using `++wordCount[word];` when word does not exist in wordCount? I always saw someone using like this, but I am not really sure about it.

Explanation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operator[]/) said:

> If k does not match the key of any element in the container, the
>   function inserts a new element with that key and returns a reference
>   to its mapped value. Notice that this always increases the container
>   size by one, even if no mapped value is assigned to the element (the
>   element is constructed using its default constructor).

and I know that [int is uninitialized in default](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization). So, I think it's not safe to increase map value directly like this, is that right?

Comment: I think a default-constructed int is 0... e.g. `int()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting cppreference's docs on [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at)

> When the default allocator is used, this results in the key being copy constructed from key and the mapped value being value-initialized.

The keyword is **[value-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)**.  An `int` that's value-initialized is zero.

Here's the [official reference](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) (C++14, 23.5.4.3 paragraph 2, [unord.map.elem]):

> *Effects:* If the `unordered_map` does not already contain an element whose key is equivalent to `k`, the first operator inserts the value `value_type(k, mapped_type())` and the second operator inserts the
>   value `value_type(std::move(k), mapped_type())`.

Notice the `mapped_type()`, which for `mapped_type = int` would construct a zero-valued `int`.